# How to perform same action as changing Windows 7 display from Landscape to Portrait

Tags: c++, c, winapi, graphics, windows-7

I need to write a program which programmatically changes the Landscape mode to Portrait of a touchscreen in Windows 7.  The resolution is 1920 x 1080 and I thought I could switch the 1920 with the 1080 and use ChangeDisplaySettings or ChangeDisplaySettingsEx to make the change.  but it doesn't work.

Windows CE has some sort of rotate feature, so I tried that.  as in:

```
devmode.dmFields = DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION;
devmode.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_90;
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(NULL,&devmode,NULL,CDS_RESET,NULL);
```

But that didn't work on a normal test desktop PC.

I can do this through Control Panel, Display, Screen Resolution, choose Portrait, so should I not be able to do via Windows API?

How can I make this change in code?

EDIT

I tried this code, but I get DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE returned by ChangeDisplaySettings.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
DEVMODE dm;
   // initialize the DEVMODE structure
   ZeroMemory(&dm, sizeof(dm));
   dm.dmSize = sizeof(dm);

   if (0 != EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm))
   {
      std::cout << "Orientation\n";
      switch(dm.dmDisplayOrientation) {
      case DMDO_DEFAULT: std::cout << "DMDO_DEFAULT\n"; break;
      case DMDO_90: std::cout << "DMDO_90\n"; break;
      case DMDO_180: std::cout << "DMDO_180\n"; break;
      case DMDO_270: std::cout << "DMDO_270\n"; break;
      }

      std::cout << "Panning height: " << dm.dmPanningHeight << '\n'
                << "Panning width: " << dm.dmPanningWidth << '\n';

      std::cout << "Colour resolution: " << dm.dmBitsPerPel << " bits per pixel\n";

      std::cout << "Height in pixels: " << dm.dmPelsHeight << '\n';
      std::cout << "Width in pixels: " << dm.dmPelsWidth << '\n';

      if(dm.dmPelsHeight > dm.dmPelsWidth) {
          std::cout << "Screen should be rotated 90 degrees\n";

          std::cout << "Do you want to rotate display 90 degrees? (y or n)\n";
          char ch;
          std::cin >> ch;
          if(ch == 'y') {
              // swap height and width
              DWORD tmp = dm.dmPelsHeight;
              dm.dmPelsHeight = dm.dmPelsWidth;
              dm.dmPelsWidth = tmp;
              dm.dmFields = DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

              // determine new orientation
              switch (dm.dmDisplayOrientation)
              {
                case DMDO_DEFAULT:
                dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_270;
                break;
                  case DMDO_270:
                     dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_180;
                     break;
                  case DMDO_180:
                     dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_90;
                     break;
                  case DMDO_90:
                     dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_DEFAULT;
                     break;
                  default:
                     // unknown orientation value
                     // add exception handling here
                     break;
                  }


              LONG ret = ChangeDisplaySettings(&dm, CDS_TEST); //0);
              std::cout << "ChangeDisplaySettings returned " << ret << '\n';
              switch(ret) {
                case DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL: std::cout << "display successfully changed\n"; break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_BADDUALVIEW: std::cout << "The settings change was unsuccessful because the system is DualView capable\n"; break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS: std::cout << "An invalid set of flags was passed in.\n"; break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE: std::cout << "The graphics mode is not supported.\n"; break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM: std::cout << "An invalid parameter was passed in. This can include an invalid flag or combination of flags.\n"; break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_FAILED: std::cout << "The display driver failed the specified graphics mode.\n"; break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_NOTUPDATED: std::cout << "Unable to write settings to the registry.\n"; break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_RESTART: std::cout << "The computer must be restarted for the graphics mode to work.\n"; break;


              }


          }

      }
      else
          std::cout << "Screen orientation is just fine\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: @UDIT er no, that question is about an android emulator

Comment: I mean by pressing left-ctrl + F11 , landsacpe changes to potrait , so it can simply be done programmatically using keyboard event ->  sendKeyDown(VK_LCONTROL);
sendKeyDown(VK_F11);
sendKeyUp(VK_F11);
sendKeyUp(VK_LCONTROL);    it's just simple approach :)

Comment: @UDITRAIKWAR I have a Windows 7 desktop PC, and pressing left-ctrl + F11 doesn't do anything, even when I have the focus on the desktop.

Comment: I think this is controlled by the video driver, so there's no standard Windows shortcut for changing the display orientation. With the Intel video driver, the default keyboard shortcut is different as comapred to amd or any other driver.

Comment: @UDITRAIKWAR The question you cite is about changing in the Android emulator running on windows.  NOT the actual Windows display.  Test before speak!

Comment: [This?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812499.aspx)

Comment: What does the function return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw an article on the web indicating that possibly it couldn't be done. But this code works.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   DEVMODE dm;
   // initialize the DEVMODE structure
   ZeroMemory(&dm, sizeof(dm));
   dm.dmSize = sizeof(dm);

   // only change first/default display (index=0)
   if (0 != EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm))
   {
      std::cout << "Current orientation\n";
      switch(dm.dmDisplayOrientation) {
      case DMDO_DEFAULT: std::cout << "DMDO_DEFAULT\n"; break;
      case DMDO_90: std::cout << "DMDO_90\n"; break;
      case DMDO_180: std::cout << "DMDO_180\n"; break;
      case DMDO_270: std::cout << "DMDO_270\n"; break;
      }

      std::cout << "Panning height: " << dm.dmPanningHeight << '\n'
                << "Panning width: " << dm.dmPanningWidth << '\n';

      std::cout << "Colour resolution: " << dm.dmBitsPerPel << " bits per pixel\n";

      std::cout << "Height in pixels: " << dm.dmPelsHeight << '\n';
      std::cout << "Width in pixels: " << dm.dmPelsWidth << '\n';

      if(argc != 2) {
          std::cout << "Usage: rotate_screen <angle>. Angle values: 0, 90, 180, 270. Angles are rotation clockwise. Use 0 to revert back\n";
          exit(0);
      }

      // parse parameter
      int rotate = atoi(argv[1]);  // should do something better and safer here
      if(rotate != 0 && rotate != 90 && rotate != 180 && rotate != 270) {
          std::cout << "incorrect rotation selected\n";
      }
      else {
        // swap height and width
        DWORD tmp = dm.dmPelsHeight;
        dm.dmPelsHeight = dm.dmPelsWidth;
        dm.dmPelsWidth = tmp;

        // select fields which have changed
        dm.dmFields = DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION;

        // set angle
        switch(rotate) {
        case 0:   dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_DEFAULT; break;
        case 90:  dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_90; break;
        case 180: dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_180; break;
        case 270: dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_270; break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Something went wrong, aborting\n";
            exit(0);
        }

        LONG ret = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(NULL, &dm, NULL, 0, NULL); //CDS_RESET, NULL); //0);
        std::cout << "ChangeDisplaySettingsEx returned " << ret << '\n';
        switch(ret) {
        case DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL: std::cout << "display successfully changed\n"; break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_BADDUALVIEW: 
            std::cout << "The settings change was unsuccessful because the system is DualView capable\n"; 
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS: std::cout << "An invalid set of flags was passed in.\n"; break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE: std::cout << "The graphics mode is not supported.\n"; break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM: std::cout << "An invalid parameter was passed in. This can include an invalid flag or combination of flags.\n"; break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_FAILED: std::cout << "The display driver failed the specified graphics mode.\n"; break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_NOTUPDATED: std::cout << "Unable to write settings to the registry.\n"; break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_RESTART: std::cout << "The computer must be restarted for the graphics mode to work.\n"; break;
        }
      }
   } // enum worked
}
```